# SQL Server : convert varchar to numeric with sign at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a varchar value like this:

```
DECLARE @TestConvert VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234.94-'
```

And I want to convert this value to a `decimal(5,2)` likes this:

```
SELECT CAST(@TestConvert AS DECIMAL(18, 4))
```

The problem is the sign at the end of the value.

If the sign is at the beginning like this:

```
DECLARE @TestConvert VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234.94-'
```

I have no problem. Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: a `decimal(5,2)` would **not** be large enough to hold your value of `-1234.94` - it would **only** allow for 5 digits total, 2 of which *after* the decimal point (and thus **3** before the decimal point). You would need **at least** a `decimal(6,2)` to hold this value!

Comment: `PARSE('123.94-' as decimal(6,2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL2012 and above `PARSE` will handle this. (My test box is running 2016 so apologies if this doesn't work for you)

```
DECLARE @TestConvert VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234.94-'
SELECT PARSE(@TestConvert AS  DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS Converted

Converted
---------------------------------------
-1234.9400

(1 row(s) affected)
```

`PARSE` documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316(v=sql.110).aspx

and related

`TRY_PARSE` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  DECLARE @TestConvert VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234.94-' 
  SELECT CAST((RIGHT(@TestConvert,1)+LEFT(@TestConvert,LEN(@TestConvert)-1)) as DECIMAL(18,4))
```

This answer assumes the '-' symbol will always be at the end

If there are values sometimes formatted as -1234.94 then you could do:

```
 DECLARE @TestConvert VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234.94-' 
 SELECT
 CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@TestConvert)=1  THEN 
 CAST(@TestConvert AS Decimal(18,4) )
 ELSE
CAST((RIGHT(@TestConvert,1)+LEFT(@TestConvert,LEN(@TestConvert)-1)) as DECIMAL(18,4))
END
```

Comment: So `'-1234.94'` isn't expected? Seems a little bit unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TestConvert VARCHAR(MAX) = '1234.94-'

if(charindex('-', @TestConvert) = len(@TestConvert))
begin
    set @TestConvert = replace(@TestConvert, '-', '')
    select 0 - cast(@TestConvert as DECIMAL(6, 2))
end
else
    select cast(@TestConvert as DECIMAL(6, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
declare @val as nvarchar(max)='5656.99-'

select case when CHARINDEX('+',reverse(@val))=1 or CHARINDEX('-',reverse(@val))=1 then
CAST(REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(@val),1,1,'')) as decimal(18,2)) else cast(@val as decimal(18,2)) end
```

hope it'll convert value for any cases.